# How to split json array into sub array using jolt specifcation in Apache Nifi?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am tring to prepare a `jolt` specification for the expected output, please help me out.

###### Note:

The expected output: where credit is in array with multiple field, then json will split into subjson where `InvoiceMonth` will be same as input only but in 1st subjson the `InvoiceMonth` value has as it is remaining subjsons `InvoiceMonth` values needs to be 0.

Input:

```json
[
  {
    "InvoiceMonth": "202306",
    "credit": {
      "name": [
        "7828credit:0",
        "2738credit:0"
      ],
      "amount": [
        "2.5E-5",
        "5.0E-5"
      ],
      "full_name": [
        "Committed USAGE",
        "Committed USAGE "
      ],
      "id": [
        "7822credit:0",
        "2732credit:0"
      ],
      "type": [
        "COMMITTEDDISCOUNT",
        "COMMITTEDDISCOUNTBASE"
      ]
    },
    "resource_name": "projects-2",
    "resource_global_name": "//https.googleapis.com/",
    "label": ""
  }
]
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "InvoiceMonth": "202306",
    "credit": {
      "name": "7822credit:0",
      "amount": "2.5E-5",
      "full_name": "Committed",
      "id": "7822credit:0",
      "type": "COMMITTEDUSAGE"
    },
    "resource_name": "projects-2",
    "resource_global_name": "//https.googleapis.com/",
    "label": ""
  },
  {
    "InvoiceMonth": "0",
    "credit": {
      "name": "2738credit:0",
      "amount": "5.0E-5",
      "full_name": "Committed ",
      "id": "2738_credit:0",
      "type": "COMMITTEDUSAGEDISCOUNT"
    },
    "resource_name": "projects-2",
    "resource_global_name": "//https.googleapis.com/",
    "label": ""
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "credit": {
          "*": {
            "0": {
              "@3,InvoiceMonth": "[#2].InvoiceMonth", // go up the tree three levels to reach the level of the attribute and grab its value
              "@": "[#2].&3.&2",
              "@3,resource_name": "[#2].resource_name",
              "@3,resource_global_name": "[#2].resource_global_name",
              "@3,label": "[#2].label"
            },
            "*": {
              "#0": "[#2].InvoiceMonth", // all values expect for the first one for the attribute is set to zero
              "@": "[#2].&3.&2",
              "@3,resource_name": "[#2].resource_name",
              "@3,resource_global_name": "[#2].resource_global_name",
              "@3,label": "[#2].label"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // pick only one component from the reformed arrays with the multiple repeating components 
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where the main idea is looping through the arrays under `"credit"` object, and then adding the other attributes.

Comment: Thanks Barbaros, but the InvoiceMonth value for 1st subjson will be as it is and remaining jsons the invoicemonth needs to be 0. Check the expected output you can see the Invoicemonth value zero for 2nd subjson.